# alert() not appearing on load in jQuery document ready handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code I use to show a message on my webpage.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        alert('success');
    });
</script>
```

However, after the page loads it shows me nothing.

Comment: any errors in your console?

Comment: Make sure your refs to the .js library files in your <script ...> tags are correct.  Also, you don't need the 'e' in 'function(e)'; 'function()' will do just fine.  Try removing that 'e' and see if that isn't messing you up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try loading the jquery files from a cdn, unless you're already hosting it-

e.g.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

edit:

you say it's already apart of your server, I personally prefer making absolute paths to files..

e.g.

`<script src="http://your.server.com/path/to/the/files/jquery.1.9.js"`

obviously you'll need to get the actual path, and make sure it's got the correct permissions

Comment: it's already hosted on my server, is there anyway i can fix it.

Comment: @FahadBhuyian you can check the path to your js-files.

Comment: everything is working fine like $.post(); $().hide();, without click and ready function like we wrote in every script.